# get a lighter color from threejs Color

Tags: colors, three.js

I need to get a lighter shade from a variable color in threejs. Is there a quick way of doing this?
basically just lighten whatever color is given. I am looking through https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Color and i dont see anything obvious, but I am not also familiar with color manipulation and if there's a simple way of just adding something of multiplying something to get the result I need.
Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The `Color` can be constructed from HSL:

`const color6 = new THREE.Color("hsl(0, 100%, 50%)");`

Using the third parameter `lightness` is more appropriate in your case.

Here is a HSL color demo:

https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_hsl.asp

It is more directly to change HSL color by function `offsetHSL`:

https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Color.offsetHSL

Hope it works :)

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a way, by simply doing:

```
myColor.lerp(new Color("#FFF"), .7);
```

Comment: nice and readable!